What happens when you can't pay for knocking out a traffic light?
Bob caused an accident that resulted in a traffic light being knocked out and damaged. He has little savings and work minimum wage. His insurance has the minimum permissible limits in California. The other driver had no insurance at all. What can Bob do when the city demands that he pays for the traffic light but he has no money or assets?

What is your insurance coverage? Liability insurance usually covers something around $3 Million or more (at least in Europe), that should be enough for a traffic light. Are coverages so much lower in the US?

This site isn't for providing legal advice, but for answering hypothetical questions about the law. We can't answer a question about you, but we could answer a question about a hypothetical person.

@PMF The minimum permissible coverage for property damage in California is...drum rolls...five thousand dollars.  "Affordable insurance" almost certainly means that everything is the legal minimum. As a country we're really #1 at "Oh, your life went slightly askew? Pay up, chump!". It's actually pretty good here, but boy they get you hard when things turn for the worst.

@zibadawatimmy Oh, that's really low, considering that (I checked again) the minimum here is €5 Million, typically even €100 Million. Costs start around €300. What would the minimum cost in the US?

@PMF: A pretty common limit for a "decent" policy is $100,000 per person injured or killed, with a max of $300,000 per accident, and $50,000 for property damage. You can go up a bit from there, but it's hard to find insurers that offer anything more than $1,000,000.

@PMF What would the minimum cost in the US? - not a lot, if you don't need it. If you need it (i.e.: had any claims or traffic violations in recent history) it may be cost prohibitive to those who can only afford minimum coverage. That's why there are so many uninsured drivers in the US.

@littleadv which is technically illegal in many areas because to drive legally you have to have proof of insurance.

@littleadv Not the only factor, uninsured drivers are also correlated with illegal immigrants, as you need a drivers license to be insured, and most states require legal residency for driver's licenses.

Well, maybe, but the OP is from California where there's no such requirement

@user71659 Which is why a number of states are removing that requirement, so that illegal immigrants can get proper training to drive more safely.

Are you suggesting there is something special about knocking out a traffic light, or does the same Question apply to anything else unaffordable?

@DaleM is basically correct, but the way that the issue would present itself is not quite as described in the question.
The city will have insurance that will cover the damage to the traffic light, which will pay the claim. The insurance company will then bring a subrogation claim against the at fault party to recover the money it paid on its claim from the city, which it will pursue only if it makes economic sense for it to do so.
If the insurance company ascertains that Bob is judgment proof (or nearly so), it may decide to not invest the legal fees and time involved in pursuing the subrogation claim, knowing that doing so is likely to be a bad business proposition for it. Or, more likely, the city's insurance company would contact Bob's insurance company and settle for his minimal property damage coverage of $5,000, without bringing a lawsuit.
The city could just sue Bob. But, because Bob has insurance, Bob's insurance company would provide him a legal defense to the city's insurance company's subrogation claim, so the insurance company could expect just a simple default judgment against an unrepresented defendant. Realistically, even in this simple case, the insurance company would be out low five figures of legal fees and litigation costs (like expert witness fees and filing fees), to take the case to trial in this low stakes case.
So, in all likelihood, the city's insurance company would be happy to settle for a policy limits demand (even though it is much smaller than the city's claim for property damage which it paid), and Bob's insurance company would be happy to pay the policy limits demand, because if it didn't it would be exposed to liability for bad faith by a first party insurer for failing to take an opportunity to free Bob of any liability in excess of the policy limits.
Both insurance companies would be paying lawyers out of pocket by the hour, so both would have an incentive to reduce litigation costs if possible.
In contrast, the city's insurer might very well sue the other, uninsured driver, for the amount that Bob's insurance company didn't pay. That driver doesn't have an insurance company to provide a legal defense and will probably default, with minimal legal expenditures by the city's insurance company. The uninsured driver is probably also judgment proof right now. But, the money judgment might be collectible  at sometime in the future (e.g., when the uninsured driver wins the lottery or receives an inheritance), and would last long after the statute of limitations to sue over the accident itself expires.

There's the matter of the deductible. When I worked for a state, it was $10k before it could hit the state's self-insurance fund.

@user71659 There might be a deductible for the city's property insurance. But it also wouldn't be that unusual for a city to fully pay the entire deductible for all claims per year under the policy, and even if it didn't the deductible typically wouldn't be cost effective to sue over. A traffic light costs maybe $30K-$100K to buy and install. A $10K deductible wouldn't be worth suing over, even if the entire amount of the loss would be. Bob's policy, meanwhile wouldn't have a deductible which typically doesn't exist for liability insurance.

The same things Bob can do when he owes money to anyone

Pay it
Negotiate a lesser amount the creditor will accept and pay that
Negotiate a payment plan acceptable to the creditor
Declare bankruptcy
Not pay it and get sued, lose, have assets seized, garnishee orders, bankruptcy etc.

